# The Unknown Provider Errors for Custom filters in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Below is my app.js code.

```
var app = angular.module('SampleApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.filter('ordinal', function () {
    // Create the return function
    // set the required parameter name to **number**
    return function (number) {

        // Ensure that the passed in data is a number
        if (isNaN(number) || number < 1) {

            // If the data is not a number or is less than one (thus not having a cardinal value) return it unmodified.
            return number;
        } else {

            // If the data we are applying the filter to is a number, perform the actions to check it's ordinal suffix and apply it.        
            var lastDigit = number % 10;

            if (lastDigit === 1) {
                return number + 'st'
            } else if (lastDigit === 2) {
                return number + 'nd'
            } else if (lastDigit === 3) {
                return number + 'rd'
            } else if (lastDigit > 3) {
                return number + 'th'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have written a custom filter named as 'Ordinal.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="uuuu" />
<span ng-bind="uuuu | ordinal"></span>
```

When I am trying to use it as above, I am getting below error.

Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ordinalFilterProvider <-
>   ordinalfilter

Comment: This error can be caused by a typo. Try `.filter('Ordinal'` with a captial "O".

Comment: Do you have any other JavaScript file after that one? You probably redefined the SampleApp module.